# Parafac for crossover design studies

Tags: multilevel-analysis, crossover-study

.Hi, everybody

I have data that has 28 subjects involved in a crossover design study including 4 different treatments. The amount of variables is over 10000 (measured almost on the same scale)

In general, I can construct a 28x4x10000 tensor.

My question is whether I can use PARAFAC for such a structure or it is not really applicable for crossover study design?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your scientific goal? What are your measurements?

Comment: Scientific goal is to see if certain variables are specific for a diet.

Comment: How are your variable measured? Are they binary?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific for a diet"? Are they events that might only occur in response to that diet? Do they change in response to that diet?